# Should a builder accept primitives or value objects

Tags: php, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, builder, builder-pattern

Given an `Address` at a minimum **must** have a `$firstLine` and `$postcode` but can contain optional properties,
I am looking to implement a `builder` to ease the construction of an `Address`.

An abridged `Address` might look like:

```
class Address
{
    /**
     * @var AddressLine
     */
    private $firstLine;

    /**
     * @var null|AddressLine
     */
    private $secondLine;

    /**
     * Other properties excluded for brevity
     */
    ...

    /**
     * @var Postcode
     */
    private $postcode;

    /**
     * @param AddressLine $firstLine
     * @param null|AddressLine $secondLine
     * ...
     * @param Postcode $postcode
     */
    public function __construct(AddressLine $firstLine, AddressLine $secondLine, ... , Postcode $postcode)
    {
        $this->firstLine = $firstLine;
        $this->secondLine = $secondLine;
        ...
        $this->postcode = $postcode;
    }

    public static function fromBuilder(AddressBuilder $builder)
    {
        return new self(
            $builder->firstLine(),
            $builder->secondLine(),
            ... ,
            $builder->postcode()
        );
    }
}
```

The above seems to make sense for me, a public `constructor` which protects its invariants through `typehints`
and allowing traditional construction, additionally a factory method which accepts an `AddressBuilder` that might look something like the following:

```
class AddressBuilder
{
    public function __construct(...)
    {
    }

    public function withSecondLine(...)
    {
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return Address::fromBuilder($this);
    }
}
```

In regards to the `AddressBuilder`, should it accept primatives which are validated during the `build()` method, or should it expect the relevant `Value Object`?

**With Primitives**

```
public function withSecondLine(string $line)
{
    $this->secondLine = $line;
}

public function build()
{
    ...
    $secondLine = new AddressLine($this->secondLine);

    return new Address(... , $secondLine, ...);
}
```

**With Value Objects**

```
public function withSecondLine(AddressLine $secondLine)
{
    $this->secondLine = $secondLine;
}

public function build()
{
    return Address::fromBuilder($this);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In regards to the AddressBuilder, should it accept primitives which are validated during the build() method, or should it expect the relevant Value Object?

Either approach is fine.

Working with primitives tends to be best when you are at the boundary of your application.  For example, when you are reading data from the payload of an http request, an API expressed in domain agnostic primitives is probably going to be easier to work with than an API expressed in domain types.

As you get closer to the core of the application, working in the domain language makes more sense, so your API is likely to reflect that.

One way to think about it is that that builder pattern is largely an implementation detail.  The consumer, in simple cases, is just a function

```
BowlingGame buildMeABowlingGameForGreatGood(int.... rolls) {
    BowlingGame.Builder builder = ...
    rolls.forEach(r -> {
        builder.addRoll(r)
    } )
    return builder.build();
}
```

and the consumers of the function don't care at all about the details.

You might even have different builder APIs, so that different client contexts can call the most suitable one

```
BowlingGame buildMeABowlingGameForGreatGood(int.... rolls) {
    BowlingGame.PrimitiveBuilder primitiveBuilder = new PrimitiveBuilder(
        new BowlingGame.ModelBuilder(...)
    );

    // ...
}
```

Where things have the potential to get interesting is if you aren't sure that the arguments are going to pass the validation checks.

```
AddressBuilder builder = ...

// Do you want to reject an invalid X here?
builder.withSecondLine(X)

// Or do you prefer to reject an invalid X here?
builder.build()
```

The builder pattern gives you a handle to the mutable state of the build in progress, which you can pass around.  So the `build` statement may be arbitrarily far away from the `withSecondLine` statement.  If you already know that `X` is valid (because it's a model value object already), then it probably doesn't matter much.  If `X` is a primitive, then you might care quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

A builder is not part of the domain driven design paradigm because it cannot be expressed as part of your domain's ubiquitous language.
If you want to DDD you should use a factory (for example, static method factory, service factory or some other form of factory) or a repo if you are deserializing from some source.

To answer your specific question about validation though: No, you don't validate your entity "later". Your entity and it's properties should never be in an invalid state because the responsibility of knowing to call the "validating" code will depend on the consumer. Furthermore you won't be able to serialize that entity when needed

Comment: What might this `Factory` look like, would it require an `AddressDTO` with all the relevant information for example?  In the `builder` example, I was never allowing my `Address` object to be in an invalid state as even with the `primitives` example, they were being converted to `VO` which protected their invariants before being passed to the `Address` object.

Comment: The factory will accept whatever it needs to to make up your object. This could be a primitive or a domain object. It depends on where the factory is located in model. Factories inside DomainServices tend to accept DomainObjects. Factories inside aggregates tend to require fewer parameters and can easily accept only primitives. Most times, DTO's are not valid DDD concepts. If using repositories, your repository should translate from your datasource to something useful in your Domain, usually an Aggregate.

Comment: Makes sense, but how do I then overcome my original issue of not wanting to depend on the consumer to remember the order of optional parameters?

Comment: Have the consumer pass in an object instead. A JSON object if the consumer is interfacing through a REST Api for example. Generally, there's something that lies between the consumer and the model - In DDD that "thing" is the Application Service. The application service can accept anything and translate that into something your domain will understand. So, you can pick an object and have your application service translate